# Change hyperlink address automatically if the TextToDisplay changes

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, hyperlink

I need a solution for the hyperlink in Excel. I want to make my entire hyperlink address auto-update if I change the text of the hyperlink.

For example, `TextToDisplay` of the hyperlink is:

```
D:/attachment/1000.jpg
```

then I change the `TextToDisplay` of the hyperlink to:

```
D:/attachment/1001.jpg
```

The hyperlink address changes the same as the display text if I change the text of that hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Formula Solution

The easist way would be to use a helper column. For example write your URLs in column A and use the following formula in column B to create the hyperlinks. Everytime you change the URL in column A it will change the hyperlink accordingly.

```
=HYPERLINK(A:A)
```

[image]

#### VBA Solution

Alternatively you can use the `Worksheet_Change` event in VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Target
        If Cell.Hyperlinks.Count = 1 Then
            Cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address = Cell.Value
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Note that this code applies to **all** hyperlinks on the worksheet. If you want to limit it to a specific range do the following changes:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A:A"))
        'limits the code to hyperlinks in column A.
        'hyperlinks in other cells than column a are not changed

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange
            If Cell.Hyperlinks.Count = 1 Then
                Cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address = Cell.Value
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: umm there is something error. 

i have so many data with different names
if i use marcos that you post it will change all the hyperlink

Comment: @RonaldSebastian Well, you need to be **much** more precise if you expect that I can help on this.

Comment: Is that marcos you post number 1 it will change all the hyperlink? Example i have hyperlink with different names 54.jpg, 101.jpg, and 102.jpg . If i change that 54 to 103 it will change 101.jpg and 102.jpg too? Same as 54 to 103.jpg? Then all of my hyperlink change to 103.jpg?

Comment: Alright thank you. What the mean macros number 2 you post? Im still not understand.

Comment: @RonaldSebastian it will only change hyperlinks in column A but not in other columns.

Comment: Entire column A? Or specific cell? Example i want to change A1 then A2 is change too?

Comment: Only the hyperlink of the cell that was changed. But note that if you copy a cell with a hyperlink that this will be the **same** hyperlink as the original cell and **not a copy** of the hyperlink. So if you change one the other cells hyperlink is changed too, because it is exactly the same hyperlink in both cells. To insert distinct hyperlinks you need to add a hyperlink to every cell manually and not to copy a hyperlinked cell!

Comment: Therefore I recommend to use the formula version which is much easier to apply.

Comment: Owh is there any solution if i copy the hyperlink and change it and the old hyperlink is not changed?

Comment: @RonaldSebastian no, a copied hyperlink is always the same as the original one. Create them one by one or use the formula (which dosn't have this behavior).

Comment: Ow then there is no solution for me to copy and change the hyperlink. Is there any other solution for me?

Comment: There is mass of data i must hyperlink :(

Comment: Then use the formula or write yourself a loop through your data to create the hyperlinks. Macro Recorder could help you to find out how to create a new hyperlink.